# MySQL First GROUP BY, then ORDER

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been searching all over, but couldn't come up with a proper solution to sort my table 'shop'.

This is how it looks:

```
Product           Price
---------------------------------
Site 1             35
Site 2             50
Site 3             15
Site 1             30
Site 2              5
```

Now I need it to look like this:

```
Product           Price
---------------------------------
Site 2             50
Site 2              5
Site 1             35
Site 1             30
Site 3             15
```

The table should be sorted starting with the highest price and then grouping it by the product.
I tried a million different queries and the closest I got was this:

```
SELECT m.* FROM shop m
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT product, MAX(price) AS maxprice FROM shop GROUP BY product ORDER BY maxprice ASC) s
    ON m.product = s.product
ORDER BY s.maxprice DESC
```

The query does it's job but sorts the prices in the group the wrong way around.

```
Product           Price
---------------------------------
Site 2              5
Site 2             50
Site 1             30
Site 1             35
Site 3             15
```

What am I doing wrong? Help is much appreciated!

Best and thanks a million!

Comment: Is this the original query and data set you are facing this problem with,i have tried in [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5eb64/1) it looks fine to me

Comment: You're only joining on half the condition - and there's no apostrophe in that kind of "its"

Comment: It's not the exact original query @M Khalid Junaid since I wanted to keep the question basic and easy to understand (as well as for me to learn).
Thanks for the hint @Strawberry, I'm not a native english speaker, so please forgive me.

Comment: Forgive? Don't worry - the vast majority of us natives get that wrong too!

Comment: Just joking @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select x.product, x.price from 
(Select product, max(price) as mprice from shop
group by product) as tbl inner join shop x on tbl.product = x.product
order by tbl.mprice desc, x.Price desc
```

I also notice you created a fiddle would have saved me some time but here is the update fiddle

```
SELECT s.product, s.Price
from (Select product, max(price) as mprice
   from shop group by product) as tbl
   inner join shop s on s.product = tbl.product
order by tbl.mprice desc, s.price desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5eb64/3

Comment: That produces the exact result you requested above so unless I'm missing something or you are not quite clear

Comment: No, the results are as you requested: like above but the prices are ordered differently.  The answer to your question is that `ORDER BY` statements in subqueries are not processed.  Most RDBMSs (pretty much anything not MySQL) will throw an error trying to do that without some kind of window function in the subquery.

Comment: Thanks for your help @user3277102, much appreciated. I spent hours looking for the solution. Next time I'l create a fiddle for sure.

Comment: Just FYI, 95% of the time, I see this written the other way round. Technically, it makes no difference - but it sure is easier to read!

Answer (score 0):

You've got two levels of sorting, so you need to describe both in your ORDER BY

```
ORDER BY s.maxprice DESC, m.price DESC
```